# $h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ show h(x)=f(x)g(x)

Tags: calculus, power-series

Given $f(x)= \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j$ and $g(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k$.

$f(x)$ has radius of convergence $R_1 > 0$ and $g(x)$ has radius of convergence $R_2 > 0$

Let $c_n= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j b_{n-j}$ and $R = min(R_1, R_2)$

If $h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$, show $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ on $(-R, R)$

So what I got up to was:

$h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{j=0}^n a_j b_{n-j}) x^n$

$h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j b_{n-j} x^{n-j})$

from the previous step, is

1. $h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j) (\sum_{j=0}^n b_{n-j} x^{n-j})$
2. $h(x) = (\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j) (\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_{n-j} x^{n-j})$
3. $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$

I am unsure whether step 2 is valid. Also, is there an example where h has radius
of convergence strictly greater than $R$

Answer (score 1):

Formulas (1.) and (2.) are both wrong.

For the last question, consider $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$, $g(x) = 1 - x$.